# Get cookie from redirection in the same domain

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, cookies

Let's say we have domain .aws.com. I want to do:

service1.aws.com -> 302 with cookie (same site = strict) -> service2.aws.com -> 302 with query(get cookie and append to query) -> localhost:3000?cookie=cookie -> 302 -> localhost final page.

but it doesn't work somehow. Here's the code:

```
// backend server set cookie: session-id = "ahdlahdalncac", samesite = strict
// cookie has domain = .aws.com and path = "/"

// handlePostLoginProxy is in the same domain of backend server: service2.aws.com
function handlePostLoginProxy(config: AuthConfig, req: Request, res: Response): void {
  // get cookie and set to query before redirecting to a different domain (localhost)
  res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/post_login?sessionid=${req.cookies['session-id']}`);
}

function handlePostLoginLocal(config: AuthConfig, req: Request, res: Response): void {
  res.cookie(COOKIES.sessionId, req.query.sessionid, { maxAge: 1800000 }); // max-age is 30 minutes
  res.redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

The issue is I am getting sessionid=undefined in the handlePostLoginProxy() redirection. Not sure why I cannot get cookie in the same domain.